# breadcrumb highlight extra element why?

Tags: html, css

my breadcrumb highlight >> when I click . I know somewhere my code is wrong but i cant understand where is the problem ? here is the my code  :

```
<div class="bgbrcrmb ">
    <div class="breadcrumb clearfix">
        <ul class="breadc">
            <li ><a class="you-are-here" href="#" >You Are Here</a></li>
            <li><a class="home"href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="grandparent" href="#">Grand Parent</a></li>
            <li><a class="parent" href="#">Parent</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#" class="child">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.breadcrumb{
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    margin-top:0px;
    list-style:none; 
    background-color:#333;
}
.breadcrumb li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none ;
}
.breadcrumb li + li :before{
    font-size: 9px; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-decoration: none ;
    content:">>"; 
}
.breadcrumb :hover{
    color:#FFFF00;
    text-decoration:underline; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

#### css

```
.breadcrumb{
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
margin-top:0px;
list-style:none; 
background-color:#333;

}
.breadcrumb li {
display:inline-block;
list-style:none ;

}
.breadcrumb li :before{
font-size: 9px; 
color: #FFFFFF; 
content:">>"; 
}
.breadcrumb li :hover{
color:#FFFF00;
}
```